# Is there a library to make custom markers for Google Maps API V3 by setting the marker's icon, labels and opacity?

Tags: google-maps, markers

Is there a library to make custom markers for Google Maps V3 by controling the icon, labels and opacity?

This library for Google Maps API V2, [Labeled Markers](http://gmaps-utility-library-dev.googlecode.com/svn/tags/labeledmarker/1.4/examples/airportmap.html), seems OK, but I was hoping for a V3 version, and was curious about opacity control also?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Label Marker Class** Libary v3

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerwithlabel/docs/examples.html

Note: Be sure to include markerwithlabel.js or markerwithlabel_packed.js in your document header after the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 has been included.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something, but arent you just after the [MarkerImage class](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage) in the default v3API?

> Defines an image to be used as the
>   icon or shadow for a Marker.

Comment: Thanks .....I played with MarkerImage class...it is a simple way to meet most of my needs except for it doesnt seem to have the fine control of Label Marker Class, above from @Mapperz...specially to have each marker appear as a customized label